# How to replace special characters in a string?

Tags: java, string

I have a string with lots of special characters. I want to remove all those, but keep alphabetical characters.

How can I do this?

Comment: Look this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438854/replace-unicode-control-characters-existing-solution

Answer (score 211):

That depends on what you mean. If you just want to get rid of them, do this:
*(Update: Apparently you want to keep digits as well, use the second lines in that case)*

```
String alphaOnly = input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+","");
String alphaAndDigits = input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+","");
```

or the equivalent:

```
String alphaOnly = input.replaceAll("[^\\p{Alpha}]+","");
String alphaAndDigits = input.replaceAll("[^\\p{Alpha}\\p{Digit}]+","");
```

(All of these can be significantly improved by precompiling the regex pattern and storing it in a constant)

Or, with [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
private static final CharMatcher ALNUM =
  CharMatcher.inRange('a', 'z').or(CharMatcher.inRange('A', 'Z'))
  .or(CharMatcher.inRange('0', '9')).precomputed();
// ...
String alphaAndDigits = ALNUM.retainFrom(input);
```

But if you want to turn accented characters into something sensible that's still ascii, look at these questions:

- [Converting Java String to ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707977/converting-java-string-to-ascii/3708078#3708078)
- [Java change áéőűú to aeouu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122170/java-change-aeou-to-aeouu/4122207#4122207)
- [ń ǹ ň ñ ṅ ņ ṇ ṋ ṉ ̈ ɲ ƞ ᶇ ɳ ȵ --> n or Remove diacritical marks from unicode chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453171/n---n------------n-or-remove-diacritical-marks-from)

Comment: when i am using this function it is removing all numbers as well.but i dont want numbers to remove.just want to remove special characters.Please suggest something..

Comment: well you said you only wanted the alphabet. But I'll update my answer in a minute

Comment: I want to concat string but with some condition like                 1.If there is only one result no concat required  2.If result is more than 1 than concat string in the following form example: stack+over+flow

Comment: @Tanu that's a different question. Make it a new one

Comment: What if I don't want spaces to be removed? or say all spaces like tabs, newlines collapsed as only one space?

Comment: @damned a) that's a completely different question. feel free to ask it. b) have a look at Guava's CharMatcher class. It does all that and more: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html

Comment: It misses pi symbol (π)

Answer (score 85):

I am using this.

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\W", "");
```

It replace all special characters from string.

Here

\w : A word character, short for [a-zA-Z_0-9]

\W  : A non-word character

Comment: Does not work for <script>alert('XSS Attack')</script>. How to remove '<', '>','\' characters?

Answer (score 15):

You can use the following method to keep alphanumeric characters.

```
replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
```

And if you want to keep only alphabetical characters use this

```
replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
```

Comment: For space use `replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", "");`

Answer (score 8):

Replace any special characters by

```
replaceAll("\\your special character","new character");
```

ex:to replace all the occurrence of * with white space

```
replaceAll("\\*","");
```

*this statement can only replace one type of special character at a time

Comment: Definitely what I was looking for when I saw the question title "How to replace special characters in a string?"  thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Following the example of the [Andrzej Doyle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11537115/1763602), I think the better solution is to use `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.stripAccents()`:

```
package bla.bla.utility;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class UriUtility {
    public static String normalizeUri(String s) {
        String r = StringUtils.stripAccents(s);
        r = r.replace(" ", "_");
        r = r.replaceAll("[^\\.A-Za-z0-9_]", "");
        return r;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string Output = Regex.Replace(Input, @"([ a-zA-Z0-9&, _]|^\s)", "");
```

Here all the special characters except space, comma, and ampersand are replaced. You can also omit space, comma and ampersand by the following regular expression.

```
string Output = Regex.Replace(Input, @"([ a-zA-Z0-9_]|^\s)", "");
```

Where Input is the string which we need to replace the characters.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function I used to remove all possible special characters from the string

```
let name = name.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%!.„'":*‚^_¤?<>|@ª{«»§}©®™ ]/g, '').toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Can you explain the regex a bit?

Comment: i recommend that you add notes in your answer section to explain your code. Please read more about [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic regular expressions on strings to find all special characters or use pattern and matcher classes to search/modify/delete user defined strings. This link has some simple and easy to understand examples for regular expressions: http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get unicode for that junk character from charactermap tool in window pc and add \u e.g. \u00a9 for copyright symbol.
Now you can use that string with that particular junk caharacter, don't remove any junk character but replace with proper unicode.

Answer (score 0):

For spaces use "[^a-z A-Z 0-9]" this pattern