# How to strip "control characters" from a CharSequence?

Tags: java

I have `CharSequence source, int start, int end`

I would like to strip all "control characters" from source between start and end and return this as a new CharSequence

by "control character" I mean undeseriable characters like Tab and Return, line feeds and such... basically all that was in ASCII < 32 (space) ... but I don't know how to do it in this "modern age"

what is a `char`? is it unicode? How can I remove these "control characters" ?

Comment: Have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283351/how-to-replace-special-characters-in-a-string

Comment: Use [`String#replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you can get the whole source into memory, you can do this:

```
String tmp = source.toString();
String prefix = tmp.substring(0, start-1);
String suffix = tmp.substring(end+1);
String middle = tmp.substring(start, end).replaceAll("\\s", "");
CharSequence res = prefix + middle + suffix;
```

Comment: How does this do anything with control characters?

Comment: @HighlandMark OP calls "control characters" what's commonly known as "whitespace" (by "control character" I mean undesirable characters like Tab and Return, line feeds and such...); `replaceAll()` removes all such characters from the beginning and from the end of a string.

Comment: Converting a CharSequence to a String will remove any special formatting (for instance bolded characters).

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`CharSequence.subSequence(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#subSequence%28int,%20int%29) and [`String.replaceAll(String, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) as follows:

```
source.subSequence(0, start).toString() + source.subSequence(start, end).toString().replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", "") + source.subSequence(end, source.length()).toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use 
`Character.isISOControl(char)` if using latest Guava library. 
Yes char is Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

Using Guava's [`CharMatcher`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#CharMatcher):

```
return CharMatcher.JAVA_ISO_CONTROL.removeFrom(string);
```

Comment: example does not compile in latest guava library.