# Parse the text from Special characters in Android

Tags: android, parsing, text, special-characters

I am getting the Text from the Database which I have to display in my View. I am getting the Text something like this:

Surgery - Federal University of S�o Paulo, 04-18 11:18:30.092: E/AdapterSpeakers(576): Photo Therapy in Health Sciences � Nupen.

Now I need to remove the Special characters " � " from the above text. 
I have tried HTML.from HTML along with the URLDecoder.decode("My Text", HTTP.UTF_8). But It dosen't work.

Can anyone Please help me out here.

Thanks,
david brown.

Comment: [Check this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283351/how-to-replace-special-characters-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the special character you are getting in the Text is not really a special character (�), it is something unreadable format. You can't parse such characters...

Comment: Please provide some solution @Manjunath

Comment: Which characters you want to parse? @DeepikaLalra