# Want to get the Special Character Parsed in the Response

Tags: android, parsing, special-characters

I am getting the Special Character " ã " and a dash sign " - " in my Text Response originally and When I perform the setText() on that text it shows me " � " sign at both the Places in my Device and emulator.

I want to show what exactly I have in the response, I have no clue what I do to look like what it actually is. I have googled much and tried various stuff like UTF-8, ISO Encoding Standards and HTML.fromHTML and others, but all useless.

Does anyone have the answer for this.

Thanks
DavidBrown

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse the text from Special characters in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203647/parse-the-text-from-special-characters-in-android)

Comment: You posting the same question even you marked answer right.

Comment: I know the question is Same, But the answer I have given right is for the belief that this is not a special character.

Comment: I am still seeking for the Solution dear. So please can You give me the Solution instead of Stretching Out the Bugs in the Question.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the character as an Object and then retrieve the object and set it in the textview.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace these special character with their ascii code either at server side or at client side. see if this works