# Replacing special character from a String in Android

Tags: java, regex

I have a String as folder/File Name. I am creating folder , file with that string. This string may or may not contain some charters which may not allow to create desired folder or file

e.g

```
String folder = "ArslanFolder 20/01/2013";
```

**So I want to remove these characters with "_"**

Here are characters

```
private static final String ReservedChars = "|\?*<\":>+[]/'";
```

What will be the regular expression for that? I know replaceAll(); but I want to create a regular expression for that.

Comment: Btw, you have a compiler error, invalid escape sequence.

Comment: The folder name is from server side in a JSON

Comment: @Arslan: Not in the folder name, in the `ReservedChars` string.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use this code:

```
String folder = "ArslanFolder 20/01/2013 ? / '";
String result = folder.replaceAll("[|?*<\":>+\\[\\]/']", "_");
```

And the result would be:

```
ArslanFolder 20_01_2013 _ _ _
```

you didn't say that space should be replaced, so spaces are there... you could add it if it is necessary to be done.

Comment: Why have you escaped everything in character class?

Answer (score 1):

I used one of this:

```
String alphaOnly = input.replaceAll("[^\\p{Alpha}]+","");
String alphaAndDigits = input.replaceAll("[^\\p{Alpha}\\p{Digit}]+","");
```

See this link:
[Replace special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283351/how-to-replace-special-characters-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

**This is correct solution:**

```
String result = inputString.replaceAll("[\\\\|?\u0000*<\":>+\\[\\]/']", "_");
```

Kent answer is good, but he isnt include characters `NUL` and `\`.

Also, this is a secure solution for replacing/renaming text of user-input file names, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
replaceAll("[\\W]", "_");
```

It will replace all non alphanumeric characters with underscore

Comment: But I need to replace only specific set of characters