# how to remove special characters from string in a file using java

Tags: java, regex, special-characters

I have text file it contains following information.My task is to remove special symbols from that text file.My input file conatins

`This is sample CCNA program. it contains CCNP™`.

My required output string:

```
This is sample CCNA program. it contains CCNP.
```

how to do this please suggest me.

thanks

Comment: What constitutes a special character?

Comment: Can your string contain other unicode letters also?

Answer (score 8):

This should work, "if you're looking to retain only ASCII (0-127) characters in your string":

```
String str = "This is sample CCNA program. it contains CCNP™";
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7f]+", "");
```

Comment: That’s wrong. ASCII is code points 0–127, because 128–255 are not ASCII.

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to remove all special characters from your strings? If so:

```
String alphaOnly = input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+","");
String alphaAndDigits = input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+","");
```

Please see [Sean Patrick Floyd's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283351/how-to-replace-special-characters-in-a-string) answer to a possible duplicate question.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it from a Unicode point of view:

```
String s = "This is sample CCNA program. it contains CCNP™. And it contains digits 123456789.";
String res = s.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{P}\\p{Nd}\\s]+", "");
System.out.println(res);
```

will print out:

> This is sample CCNA program. it contains CCNP. And it contains digits 123456789.

`\\p{...}` is a [Unicode property](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop)

`\\p{L}` matches all letters from all languages

`\\p{M}` a character intended to be combined with another character (e.g. accents, umlauts, enclosing boxes, etc.).

`\\p{P}` any kind of punctuation character.

`\\p{Nd}` a digit zero through nine in any script except ideographic scripts.

So this regex will replace every character that is not a letter (also combined letters), a Punctuation, a digit or a withespace character (`\\s`).

Answer (score 1):

```
 ^[\\u0000-\\u007F]*$
```

With this you allow only ASCCI characters, but you need to say us what is for you an special character.

Answer (score 0):

```
       String  yourString = "This is sample CCNA program. it contains CCNP™";
       String result = yourString.replaceAll("[\\™]","");       
       System.out.println(yourString);
       System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like:

```
Normalizer.decompose(str, false, 0).replaceAll("\\p{InSuperscriptsAndSubscripts}+", "");
```

but you need to find proper Unicode group or groups ([Unicode Blocks](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/Blocks.txt)).

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to really define what special characters are in your instance.

If you are not a fan of RegEx, you could consider using some methods out of the `Character` class. See sample below:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String test = "This is sample CCNA program. it contains CCNP™";

        System.out.println("Character\tAlpha or Letter\tWhitespace");

        for (char c : test.toCharArray()) {
            System.out.println(
                    c + "\t\t"
                    + Character.isLetterOrDigit(c) + "\t\t" 
                    + Character.isWhitespace(c));
        }
    }
}
```

There are other methods that you could use in addition to the ones above. Look at the `Character` class API.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative option to regex to exclude chars > 128.

```
    String s = "This is sample CCNA program. it contains CCNP™";


    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) > 128) {
            s = s.substring(0,  i) 
                    + s.substring(i + 1);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class replacespecialchar {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String before="";

        String after="";
        Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter string with special char");
        before=in.nextLine();

         for (int i=0;i<before.length();i++)
          {
              if (before.charAt(i)>=65&&before.charAt(i)<=90 || before.charAt(i)>=97&&before.charAt(i)<=122)  
              {
                    after+=before.charAt(i);
              }
          }

        System.out.println("String with special char "+before);
        System.out.println("String without special char "+after);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above about removing characters > 128 was very helpful.  Thank you.

However, it did not cover some situations such as 2 bad characters in a row or a bad character at the end of the string.  Here are my modifications that remove all special characters except tab and new line.

```
  // Remove all special characters except tab and linefeed
  public static String cleanTextBoxData(String value) {
    if (value != null) {
    int beforeLen = value.length();
       for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
         if ( ((value.charAt(i)<32) || (value.charAt(i)>126)) &&
            ((value.charAt(i)!=9) && (value.charAt(i)!=10)) ) {
           if ((value.charAt(i)<32) || (value.charAt(i)>126)) {
             if (i==value.length()-1) {
               value = value.substring(0,i);
             } else {
            value = value.substring(0,i) + value.substring(i+1);
            i--;
             }
        }
           if (i == value.length()) {
             break;
           }
         }
       }
       int dif = beforeLen - value.length();
       if (dif > 0) {
         logger.warn("Found and removed {} bad characters from text box.", dif);
       }

    }
      return value;
  }
```