# replace character '@' in java android

Tags: java, android, str-replace

i want to replace character `'@'` and `'.'` to `'_'` from my string . I can replace char `'.'` to `'_'` but cant replace char `'@'` .

```
public String getemailparsing(String email){
        String result="";
        char keong = 64;
        for(int i=0; i<email.length();i++){
            if(email.charAt(i) == '@' ){
                result = email.replace('@', '_'); //this is NOT working
            }else if(email.charAt(i) == '.'){
                result = email.replace('.', '_'); //this one is working
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

any idea to replace char '@' ...

Comment: why you directly not replace both character instead of char loop ? when you directly replace this both character is replace if match found other noting will be replace

Comment: can i do replace 2 char whit 1 char ?? any idea ?

Comment: Google Regular Expression Java

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283351/how-to-replace-special-characters-in-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String getEmailParsing(String email){
    return email.replaceAll("[@.]+","_");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply the little change as shown in below code. And you will get your desired output.

```
public String getemailparsing(String email) {
        String result = email;

        if (email.contains("@")) {
            result = result.replace('@', '_'); 
        }
        if (email.contains(".")) {
            result = result.replace('.', '_'); 
        }
        return result;
    }
```