# How to clean dirty text using java

Tags: java, twitter, text, filtering, dirty-data

I am working on collecting data from twitter and making processing on it, but i have the problem that: text is dirty,

example :

```
String dirtyText="this*is#a*&very_dirty&String";
```

example :

```
String dirtyText="All f dis happnd bcause u gave ur time, talent n passion.";
```

please i want it as simple as possible.

Comment: your input dirty string does not match with your output dirty string?

Comment: For us to suggest a solution, you must tell us what your requirements mean by "clean"

Comment: First one might be doable by removing non alphabetic character. But there is no "simple" way of doing the second one

Comment: i want to analyze people text in twitter (tokenize,POS) but if text in that form, this will not work 

or if there is another way to deal with it

Comment: @KickButtowski i get text to analyze and use it in my project ,,

Comment: @Samuel clean means convert text : 
(this*is#a*&very_dirty&String --> this is very dirty string) .....  

(All f dis happnd --> all of this happened)

Comment: @ortis ok if there is any way to do it just tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an easy problem to solve. `All f dis happnd` could be "cleaned" to produce `All *of* this happened` or `All *if* this happened`. For the first example, you can merely replace all non-alphabetic characters with spaces. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283351/how-to-replace-special-characters-in-a-string) for how to do that.

Otherwise I think you would need a natural language processor, or at the very least a spell checker. To guess what a Tweet should be in correct english is an extremely complex problem to solve. Take a look at [Jazzy](http://jazzy.sourceforge.net/) for an open source spell checker.

Answer (score 0):

public class CleaningDirtText {
/*
* remove leading and trailing spaces, and split our words into a String array.
* The split method allows you to break apart text on a given delimiter. In this
* case, we chose to use the regular expression \W, which represents anything
* that is not a word character:
*/
private static final String dirtyText = "this*is#a*&very_dirty&String";

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(dirtyText);
    String[] words =    dirtyText.toLowerCase().trim().split("[\\W\\d]+");
    // System.out.println(preparedText);
    //String[] cleanText = dirtyText.toLowerCase().trim().split("[\\W]+");
    for (String clean : words) {
        System.out.print(clean + " ");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you posting your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68839324/6670491) twice? Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68839282/edit) and explain why your code can solve OP's issue?

Answer (score 0):

public class CleaningDirtText {
private static final String dirtyText = "this*is#a*&very_dirty&String";

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*
     * remove leading and trailing spaces, and split our words into a String array.
     * The split method allows you to break apart text on a given delimiter. In this
     * case, we chose to use the regular expression \\W, which represents anything
     * that is not a word character:
     */

    System.out.println(dirtyText);
    String[] words = dirtyText.toLowerCase().trim().split("[\\W\\d]+");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(words[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("\nsee the cleand text:-");
    for (String clean : words) {
        System.out.print(clean + " ");
    }
}
```

}