# How to filter a Java String to get only alphabet characters?

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm generating a XML file to make payments and I have a constraint for user's full names. That param only accept alphabet characters (a-ZAZ) + whitespaces to separe names and surnames.

I'm not able to filter this in a easy way, how can I build a regular expression or a filter to get my desireable output?

Example:

`'Carmen López-Delina Santos'` must be `'Carmen LopezDelina Santos'`

I need to transform vowels with decorations in single vowels as follows: á > a, à > a, â > a, and so on; and also remove special characters as dots, hyphens, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: How is `ó` becoming `o` and btw `[a-ZA-Z]` doesn't cover `ó`

Comment: I need to transform vowels with decorations in single vowels as follows: á > a, à > a, â > a, and so on.

Comment: That requirement must be part of your question not in comments. Also don't forget to show your attempt.

Comment: @EnriMR Maybe you can check ASCII to get the values of the specials characters and then make a range.

Comment: This seems to be a decent answer for your first need (I like the Guava part) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4283366/4167384 And this for the special character remplacement : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1453284/4167384

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can first use [a Normalizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) and then remove the undesired characters:

```
String input = "Carmen López-Delina Santos";
String withoutAccent = Normalizer.normalize(input, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
String output = withoutAccent.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "");
System.out.println(output); //prints Carmen LopezDelina Santos
```

Note that this may not work for all and any non-ascii letters in any language - if such a case is encountered the letter would be deleted. One such example is the Turkish `i`.

The alternative in that situation is probably to list all the possible letters and their replacement...

Comment: This is exactly what I need because the system is waiting for my XML file doesn't allow any other character for name field

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [removeAccents](http://drillio.com/en/software/java/remove-accent-diacritic/) method with a later `replaceAll` with `[^A-Za-z ]`:

```
public static String removeAccents(String text) {
  return text == null ? null :
    Normalizer.normalize(text, Form.NFD)
        .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
}
```

> The `Normalizer` decomposes the original characters into a combination
>   of a base character and a diacritic sign (this could be multiple signs
>   in different languages). `á`, `é` and `í` have the same sign: `0301` for
>   marking the `'` accent.
>
> The `\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+` regular expression will match all
>   such diacritic codes and we will replace them with an empty string.

And in the caller:

```
String original = "Carmen López-Delina Santos";
String res = removeAccents(original).replaceAll("[^A-Za-z ]", "");
System.out.println(res);
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/xTrDfp)