# How to stop storing integers and special characters in String in Java?

Tags: java

I wrote a program to read username from keyboard. When I enter any  integer or special characters, it is taking that values and displaying on console. But I want that it should not take any integers and special characters. It should take only letters and if any integer or special character is there, then it should give the error message and should not store that value. Can anybody help me with this problem?

The program program which I wrote is

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CheckIsEmpty {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
             System.out.println("Enter User Name:: ");
             System.out.println();
             String usn = sc.nextLine();

          if (usn.trim().isEmpty()) {
               System.out.println("Don't Give Space");
               System.out.println();
          }//if
          else if (usn.isEmpty()) {
               System.out.println("User Name Is Mandatory");
               System.out.println();
          } // if
          else {
               System.out.println("Hi " + usn);
               System.out.println("Welcome To Java");
               break;
          }// else

    }//while
}//main
```

}// class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter a Java String to get only alphabet characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30780074/how-to-filter-a-java-string-to-get-only-alphabet-characters)

Comment: After you get the sc.nextLine() into your string usn variable, check if the variable contains any integers or special characters, then display error if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex here. If all characters are letters then following code will return true.

```
usn.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")
```

If an input string is having any other char it will return false.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @nagendra547. It Worked

Comment: What is the use of "+" operator in the given expression?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern matching..

boolean b = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+").matcher(username).matches();