# How to remove control characters from java string?

Tags: java, regex, string, guava

I have a string coming from UI that may contains control characters, and I want to remove all control characters except **carriage returns**, **line feeds**, and **tabs**.

Right now I can find two way to remove all control characters:

**1- using guava:**

```
return CharMatcher.JAVA_ISO_CONTROL.removeFrom(string);
```

**2- using regex:**

```
return string.replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", "");
```

Comment: So you've already got two ways of doing it... what are you asking, exactly?

Comment: And this begs the question, what kind of UI is it that allows entering control chars? Maybe you should eliminate the problem at the source.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, the above two ways removes all of them, and i want to remove all control characters except carriage returns, line feeds, and tabs

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh: Ah, I'm with you now.

Comment: Did you tried smth like this? return string.replaceAll("[\\p{Cntrl}^\r\n\t]+", ""); ?

Comment: Note that `CharMatcher.JAVA_ISO_CONTROL` is deprecated in later versions of Guava. You can use `CharMatcher.javaIsoControl()` instead

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do something like this if you want to delete all characters in other or control uni-code category

```
System.out.println(
    "a\u0000b\u0007c\u008fd".replaceAll("\\p{Cc}", "")
); // abcd
```

**Note :** This actually removes (among others) '\u008f' Unicode character from the string, not the escaped form "%8F" string.

Courtesy : [polygenelubricants](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276101/polygenelubricants) ( [Replace Unicode Control Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3439206/1575570) )

Comment: This doesn't do what the author wanted, he wanted to preserver also new lines, line feeds and tabs. The above code will remove also those.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I spent all my day to find this bug in my code. Soap http request from java was returning http status 400 but soap-ui like test environments or curl were working properly with the "same" request xml. At last I found those "invisible" chars. :)

Comment: At least put the answer in your own words..... http://stackoverflow.com/a/3439206/2347824

Answer (score 20):

One option is to use a combination of `CharMatcher`s:

```
CharMatcher charsToPreserve = CharMatcher.anyOf("\r\n\t");
CharMatcher allButPreserved = charsToPreserve.negate();
CharMatcher controlCharactersToRemove = CharMatcher.JAVA_ISO_CONTROL.and(allButPreserved);
```

Then use `removeFrom` as before. I don't know how efficient it is, but it's at least simple.

---

As noted in edits, `JAVA_ISO_CONTROL` is now deprecated in Guava; the [`javaIsoControl()`](https://guava.dev/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#javaIsoControl--) method is preferred.

Comment: `CharMatcher.javaIsoControl()` is now actual as `JAVA_ISO_CONTROL` is deprecated.

Answer (score 14):

This seems to be an option

```
    String s = "\u0001\t\r\n".replaceAll("[\\p{Cntrl}&&[^\r\n\t]]", "");
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        System.out.print((int) c + " ");
    }
```

prints `9 13 10` just like you said "except carriage returns, line feeds, and tabs".

Answer (score 9):

use these

```
public static String removeNoneAscii(String str){
    return str.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");
}

public static String removeNonePrintable(String str){ // All Control Char
    return str.replaceAll("[\\p{C}]", "");
}

public static String removeOthersControlChar(String str){ // Some Control Char
    return str.replaceAll("[\\p{Cntrl}\\p{Cc}\\p{Cf}\\p{Co}\\p{Cn}]", "");
}

public static String removeAllControlChars(String str)
{
    return removeNonPrintable(str).replaceAll("[\\r\\n\\t]", "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java regular expression, it is possible to exclude some characters in a character class. Here's a sample program demonstrate something similar:

```
class test {
    public static void main (String argv[]) {
            String testStr="abcdefABCDEF";
            System.out.println(testStr);
            System.out.println(testStr.replaceAll("[\\p{Lower}&&[^cd]]",""));
    }
}
```

It will produce this output:

```
abcdefABCDEF
cdABCDEF
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Selenium to test web screens.  I use Hamcrest asserts and matchers to search the page source for different strings based on various conditions.

```
String pageSource = browser.getPageSource();
assertThat("Text not found!", pageSource, containsString(text));
```

This works just fine using an IE or Firefox driver, but it bombs when using the HtmlUnitDriver.  The HtmlUnitDriver formats the page source with tabs, carriage returns, and other control characters.  I am using a riff on Nidhish Krishnan's ingenious answer above.  If I use Nidish's solution "out of the box," I am left with extra spaces, so I added a private method named filterTextForComparison:

```
String pageSource = filterTextForComparison(browser.getPageSource());
assertThat("Text not found!", pageSource, 
        containsString(filterTextForComparison(text)));
```

And the function:

```
/**
 * Filter out any characters embedded in the text that will interfere with
 * comparing Strings.
 * 
 * @param text
 *            the text to filter.
 * @return the text with any extraneous character removed.
 */
private String filterTextForComparison(String text) {

    String filteredText = text;

    if (filteredText != null) {
        filteredText = filteredText.replaceAll("\\p{Cc}", " ").replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ");
    }

    return filteredText;
}
```

First, the method replaces the control characters with a space then it replaces multiple spaces with a single one.  I tried doing everything at once with "\p{Cc}+?" but it didn't catch "\t " becoming "  ".

Comment: filteredText.replaceAll("\\p{Cc}", " ").replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ") - worked perfectly for me, Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Use `StringUtils.deleteWhiteSpace(text)` from [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/).

Answer (score -1):

U can use StingUtils from Spring:

```
String str = "\n\t\t\tsome text\t\t\n";
StringUtils.trimAllWhitespace(str); // some text
```

Comment: The question asks for ways to remove control characters EXCEPT whitespace control characers; this solution removes ONLY whitespace control characters.  Also this solution removes space characters, which are not usually considered control characters.